# how can I override application.properties of a jar by its calling spring boot application properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, application.properties

I am consuming a spring boot project (jar) inside another spring boot project using the maven dependency. The jar file has no properties defined in application.properties, I want to fetch the properties of current spring boot project inside the jar file. Is there any way to override the application.properties of jar.

**===============Microservice1=====================**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.jwt.security.*"})
public class MicroserviceApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceApplication1.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
jwt.auth.secret: secret
jwt.auth.token_prefix : Bearer
jwt.auth.header_string : Authorization
```

**UserController**

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class UserController
{
@RequestMapping(value="/jwt")
    public String tokens(){
        log.debug("User controller called : Token()");
        return "successful authentication";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jwt.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>securityUtils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

Now, below is configuration in the jar.

**==========securityUtils============**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
//@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
//@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jwt")
class TokenAuthenticationService {

    @Value("${jwt.auth.secret}")
    private static String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.auth.header_string}")
    private static String headerString;

    @Value("${jwt.auth.token_prefix}")
    private static String tokenPrefix;

    static void getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(headerString);
        Date referenceTime = new Date();
        if (token != null) {
            final Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(secret.getBytes())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(tokenPrefix, ""))
                    .getBody();

            if (claims == null) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("You are not authoriozed");
            } else {
                Date expirationTime = claims.getExpiration();
                if (expirationTime == null || expirationTime.before(referenceTime)) {
                    log.debug("The token is expired");
                    throw new TokenExpiredException("The token is expired");

                }
            }

        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("You are not authoriozed");
        }
    }
}
```

In TokenAuthenticationService I want to get the properties loaded from the calling microservice1

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. Can you put some code example as to how you want to get and how is ur project configured?

Comment: you can add a `ComponentScan` in your MicroService 2 which packages to scan from first microservice directory

Comment: I want to make the jar as a Utility and don't want to make it dependent on any of the packages thats you not using component scan of microservice1. What I need is any microservice with the available properties can call and get authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible depending on how you are importing and using that jar in your project.
In your projects configuration class, you need to import configuration class of JAR project like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(ConfigClassJarProject.class)
public class Application {
}
```

This will create beans of JAR project and put them in application context to utilise. While creating beans for (SecurityUtils) class it will look for configuration in properties.
Now you need to do two things, first update your securityUtils class and add colon after properties name which will set default value to null.

```
@Value("${jwt.auth.secret:}")
private static String secret;

@Value("${jwt.auth.header_string:}")
private static String headerString;

@Value("${jwt.auth.token_prefix:}")
private static String tokenPrefix;
```

Second set these configurations in properties file of your project utilising this JAR

Hope this will help.